# REST OAuth 2.0 where to store tokens

Tags: rest, session-state, oauth-2.0, wcf-web-api

I am building REST services using WCF Web API. Because REST is stateless I cannot store OAuth token in session. (this is not permanent token have expiration)
Where to store that token if not in database ? If I store in database I will have performance penalty.

Can I enable sessions in WCF Web API ?

Answer (score 0):

If a classic sql-realtion db is too slow, you may considering a non-sql db such Mongo. "[Mongo capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections)" are a good choice if token lifetime is short and they do not require major update after have been inserted.